# X does not start after removing parameters quiet splash

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, plymouth

I would like to remove the splash screen. Kubuntu 12.04 runs on my laptop with KDE 4.11 (I use the backports offered by the Kubuntu community).
In order to remove the splash at boot time,  I removed the kernel parameters `quiet  splash` in `/etc/default/grub` and did execute `update-grub`.
However, the result of this is that X does not start correctly anymore. I end up at the console login prompt. I can login and execute `startx`, which brings me to the KDE desktop.

Of course, this behaviour was not intended by me. How can I solve this issue?

Edit: I reverted the grub config file, i.e. added the parameters `quiet splash` again, which results in a correct boot (without boot messages).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Did you edit `/etc/default/gru`b from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash” to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=””` I have Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.11 using backports and I removed the parameters. It starts correctly.